# How to block the horizontal swipe function when scrolling vertically (on mobile phones)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have a function that makes a horizontal swipe of an object. How to block the horizontal swipe function / event when vertically scrolling the page.

I figured out how to block vertical scrolling, but I can't find a solution with horizontal scrolling, maybe someone faced a similar problem and can suggest an algorithm for the solution, or maybe someone has some groundwork left?

Here is a complete example on codebox (works only with touch event).

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-architecture-0k6rb?file=/src/scroll.js:2945-3250&resolutionWidth=1072&resolutionHeight=675

```js
  let ref = useRef();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isScrolling: false,
    clientX: 0, 
    scrollX: 0 
  });

  const touchStartHandler = (e) => {
    if (ref && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    setState({
      ...state,
      isScrolling: true,
      clientX: e.touches[0].clientX
    });
  };

  const touchMoveHandler = (e) => {
    if (ref && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    const { clientX, scrollX, isScrolling } = state;

    if (isScrolling === true) {
      let sX = scrollX - e.touches[0].clientX + clientX;
      let cX = e.touches[0].clientX;

      if (sX < -0) {
        sX = 0;
      } else if (sX >= 0 && sX <= 1800) {
        ref.current.scrollLeft = sX;
      }
      setState({
        ...state,
        scrollX: sX,
        clientX: cX
      });
    }
  };

  const touchEndHandler = (e) => {
    if (ref && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    setState({
      ...state,
      isScrolling: false
    });
  };
  
    useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler);
    return () => {                                               document.removeEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler);                  
      document.removeEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler);
      document.removeEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler);
    };
  });
  
    return (
    <div className={classes.charPage}>
      <div
        className={classes.items}
        ref={ref}
        onTouchStart={touchStartHandler}
        onTouchMove={touchMoveHandler}
        onTouchEnd={touchEndHandler}
      >
        {scrollBar}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      isScrolling: false,
      clientX: 0, 
      scrollX: 0,
      clientY: 0,
      scrollY: 0 
    });
    ...
    clientY: e.touches[0].clientY
    ...
    const { clientX, scrollX, clientY, scrollY, isScrolling } = state;
    ...

      let sY = scrollY - e.touches[0].clientY + clientY;
      let cY = e.touches[0].clientY;

      if (sY < -0) {
        sY = 0;
      } else if (sY >= 0 && sY <= 1800) {
        ref.current.scrollTop = sY;
      }
    ...
    scrollY: sY,
    clientY: cY
```

Comment: I only have a horizontal swipe script. And vertical is the usual scrolling without scripts, which appears only if the content does not fit into the page. So I don't know how to block horizontal swipe if I just scroll the page.

Comment: use style attribute on div: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: it is already there), I have a problem how to determine where the touch goes vertically or horizontally.

Comment: I tried to compare the difference between the X and Y coordinates, but the script doesn't work fine as the touchMove event is updated regularly.

Comment: compare start position and end position and find (endpos - startpos)

Comment: if *end position* is attached to the *touchEnd event*, then the page / object will not move with the finger))

Comment: curentpos(on touchmove event) - startpos?

Comment: The problem is that the swipe function is called while the cursor is moving, and it needs to be called only if the cursor moves to the side and block if the cursor moves to the bottom / top, you need to broadcast the event listener after calculations (endpos - startpos) somehow.

Comment: That is, the calculation needs to be done before the swipe starts, but the swipe is called when the cursor moves. It turns out that the calculation (endpos - startpos) occurs simultaneously with the swipe, and because of this, an animation bug occurs.